# What is difference between the admin panel and app in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a dummy project, I have been told to create the admin panel of this project.

I don't understand what the *admin panel* is and what an *app* is in a django project.

I saw a project in which there were 3 or 4 apps and the admin panel, how are these correlated?

Answer (score 2):

The [django admin app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#module-django.contrib.admin) is a pluggable application built into django that allows you to easily generate an interface where users with staff accounts can create, edit, delete, and view content.

The django admin itself is an app. The [django documentation defines an application as](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#module-django.apps):

> The term **application** describes a Python package that provides some set of features. Applications may be reused in various projects.
>
> Applications include some combination of models, views, templates, template tags, static files, URLs, middleware, etc. They’re generally wired into projects with the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and optionally with other mechanisms such as URLconfs, the `MIDDLEWARE` setting, or template inheritance.
>
> It is important to understand that a Django application is a set of code that interacts with various parts of the framework.